# RubyMotion fresh project gives error dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib, 2): image not found

Tags: rubymotion

An existing or new project with RubyMotion gives the following error
`dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib, 2): image not found` and simulator does not open

Comment: What OS, Xcode, and RM versions are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System details
`- Mojave
- Xcode 11.1
- Latest public Rubymotion from the website`

- Launch Xcode up and accept any terms and let it download any tools it thinks it needs to start up
- run sudo xcodebuild -license
- run sudo xcode-select --install && sudo xcode-select --reset
  make sure you're all up to date (I don't know if the installer does this already, but it doesn't hurt)
  sudo motion update 
  motion repo

---

Then for above error:
`dlopen(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/../Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib, 2): image not found`
or
`objc[98906]: Class __SwiftNativeNSIndexSetBase is implemented in both /usr/lib/swift/libswiftCore.dylib (0x7fff924d4e98) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib (0x1058f3f20)`

This copy of libswiftCore.dylib requires an OS version prior to 10.14.4.
run
`sudo cp -r /usr/lib/swift/*.dylib /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks
sudo touch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/.swift-5-staged`